# Android AsyncTask Starting Another AsyncTask

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-asynctask

I'm currently doing something like this in the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method, where `NewTask` is *not* the current task that's executing:

```
private class OlderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    //other functions (not important)

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        new NewTask().execute(null, null);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is a bad idea. Will doing so cause GC for the OlderTask to wait for the NewTask? Are there any other possible problems with using such an approach?

And if this is a problem, how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `NewTask` is inner non static class in `OlderTask` it will not prevent GC from collecting `OlderTask` unless you store reference to it in some other way.

But even if GC will wait until `NewTask` is done it should not be a big deal unless you save lot of data in `OlderTask` or create lots of copies of `OlderTask`.

So if your design requires doing that, it's ok. But it surely cleaner not to have chained tasks.

Comment: Thanks. Would the same logic also apply if `OlderTask` is creating a new `OlderTask`?

Comment: For as long as it's different instance of `OlderTask` and it does not refer to the previous instance directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

I use a callback method, So when result comes to onPostExecute I call another AsynkTask from UI, I think it is good idea, Let me know what do you think.

```
public class PatientSearchController extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {

    private PatientSearchResultHandler handler = null;

    public void onResultHandler(PatientSearchResultHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        this.handler.onResultSuccessHandler(result);
    }
}
```